# Using grep with very large vector of regular expressions in r

Tags: r, regex

I have a rather large vector (`table`) with 325k unique observations that I want to use as the list of regular expression to find matches in another vector (`data`) of 26k observations.

I am using this code below which works well if `table` and the resulting list of regular expressions is less than 3000 entries (although my guess it is the character count and not the expression as a hole that matters):

```
matches <- unique(grep(paste(table, collapse="|"), 
                       data$ID,
                       perl = TRUE,
                       value=FALSE))
```

But if 'table' and the resulting list of regular expressions is any longer than this I get the error:

> PCRE pattern compilation error - 'regular expression is too large'

The observations that I want to search have a mixed bag of character string patterns such as "xxx-yyyy", "L-cc-fff-C12Z3N-xxx", and even "Name.xxx-12N7t-p6" and so on. Because of this it is not at all realistic to parse out the portions of the string that may match one of the regular expressions in my 325k vector and use `match()` and thus my desire to use regular expressions.

What would be the best approach short of breaking my 'table' into 3000+ subsets and using the above code?

R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree" 
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing 
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) 
In R-Studio Version 0.98.1028

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Do you really need regular expressions? Or are you just looking for substrings that match exactly? Or entire string matches? Can you show some of your search strings?

Comment: If you have to get the job done you can break it up into a few searches instead of trying to force one

Comment: use `stringr`/`stringi` which use a different regex library and don't suffer from the PCRE ~65k length restriction

Comment: this is quite slow, but if this is a one-off operation then speed perhaps not important: `matches = unique(unlist(lapply(mytable, grep, x=mydata$id, value=F)))`. Tested on table and vector both with 30k entries - took about 5 minutes. So probably around one hour for your full set

Comment: dww - this seemed to work. It was slow but not something that I will run frequently anyway as you suggest; it took about 25 minutes. However, I'm not certain that it actually found all matches. Running a sample of one expression that I know how many I will find, this method did not find as many as I was expecting. Not really sure why that is, I will have to dig in tomorrow.

Comment: @AustinOverman Hmm this should work. Maybe because you also need to specify `perl=TRUE` depending how your regex are formulated? This is why it is good practice (and pretty much required) here on SO to post a minimal example, so we can iron out issues like this.

Comment: @dww So checking into the differences between the two processes it turns out that there are elements of mydata$id that are not in mytable. This is an acceptable condition for me so I retract my previous statement, your method did perform as expected. Thanks again.

Comment: @AustinOverman that's great. I'll post this as an answer below then.

Comment: careful, `table` is a function. Best not to use that as a variable

Answer (score 0):

You can check each regex string one by one in an `apply` loop.  This will be a little slow, but if speed is not important it will provide a satidfactory solution:

```
matches = unique(unlist(lapply(mytable, grep, x=mydata$id, value=F))).
```

Some reproducible data to test this on:

```
mydata = data.frame(id = paste0(sample(letters, 30000, T), 
                              sample(letters, 30000, T),
                              sample(letters, 30000, T),
                              sample(letters, 30000, T)))

mytable = paste0(sample(letters, 30000, T), 
               sample(letters, 30000, T),
               sample(letters, 30000, T),
               sample(letters, 30000, T))
```

By the way, `data` and `table` are both reserved words in R, so not great practice to use these as variable names.  I therefore called them `mytable` and `mydata` instead.

Comment: Neither `data` nor `table` are reserved words in R. They are function names, but they could be over-written with new values. If you want to see the list of reserved words in R, type `?Reserved` at your console. (Some of the reserved words are also function names.)